# Allow only property to access a variable

Tags: c#, scope

I'd like to trigger a method every-time a value is changed in my list.

The top answer on other questions related to this is to use a property, which I have (example below)

**However**, I think it would help me prevent any accidental bugs if I deny anything other than that property having access to the 'core' list it changes (for lack of better understanding what the term is) .

Below is my example property with a get and set accessor.

```
private List<Things>myPrivateList; // Only the Property should be able to access

private List<Things>MyPrivateList // Only the class its in can touch this
{
    get { return myPrivateList; }
    set
    {
        myPrivateList = value;
        coolMethodThatNeedsToRunEverytime();
    }
}

public List<Things>getMyPrivateList // Any class outside can read this
{
   get { return myPrivateList; }
}
```

I might be going about this the wrong way though, it would useful to know if you have any suggestions for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks very much in advance for any advice / example you may have.

Comment: Private properties are only available inside the same class, so you just need to keep other methods from touching it. No special implemented is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Orel. My worry is that I'm personally prone to accidentally writing **m**yPrivateList instead of **M**yPrivateList when writing code within that class. A small spelling mistake could break things. I could always change **m**yPrivateList variable name to something ridiculous like 'dontTouchThisListGoAway' but that doesn't seem proper.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the list being added to in any other class?

Comment: The answer is no - by definition, private fields are accessible throughout the class and this cannot be changed. However you may be able to refactor your class to achieve something similar to what you are trying to do. That said, your code has a number of issues so its difficult to help without seeing more clearly what you are actually trying to achieve with your code. I suggest posting your real code so we can see the use case.

Comment: Hi Steve - No I don't believe I do. The list itself should only be modified by the class that initializes it.

Hi cbp, what issues were you able to pick up on in the example?

Comment: Such accidents are one reason to favour `_` prefixes on private fields, though others argue against them.

Comment: Jon - Its useful to hear the practical reason why we add the _ prefix to private variables in methods. I tend to just do it because I presumed its 'the correct' way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with one property :

```
public List<Things>MyPrivateList // Only the class its in can touch this
{
    get { return myPrivateList; }
    private set
    {
       myPrivateList = value;
        coolMethodThatNeedsToRunEverytime();
    }
}
```

Doing this, the setter will be private and the getter public

Comment: Oh thats a much better way of doing it.

Comment: I just posted something wrong so I've changed it. But this does not solve the problem as there is still a myPrivateList and MyPrivateList within the class. Now it just doesn't matter which one is used. But a good solution.

Comment: I've actually just realised. Even though I've used your suggestion of adding 'private' on to set, I am still able to set this value from outside of the class?

Comment: On looking at the further, its actually using 'get' when modifying the list.

Comment: Is the problem that the list can be modified outside of the class?

Comment: How can tou modify the list outside of the class using the get ? Can you give a code sample doing that ?

Comment: By adding or removing items from the list instance for example. E.g.: foo.MyPrivateList.Clear().

Comment: It's because you are getting a reference to your list and not a copy. If you don't want your object to be affected by some instance method, you have to create a property which retrieve a copy of your object and not the object